# Get the value of a cookie #Python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have tried searching on google and going through some documentation and sample codes but I did not get how to read the value of a cookie to test on an if statement.

I am creating the cookie with the name 'sessionid' and the value of it is the hash of the user email.

```
sessionid = hashlib.md5(user.encode('utf')).hexdigest() 
#generates the session id for the cookie   

response = make_response(open('LoginPassed.xml').read())
response.set_cookie('sessionid', sessionid)
```

I want to check if the cookie exists and if I can say that a specific email has visited the site...

```
  for name in request.cookies:

  #I am trying to get the value of a sessionid cookie to compare if that
  #hash matches with the hash value of the email sent

       value = request.cookies.get('sessionid')
       # value = request.cookies I also tried this
       items = value.items

       for a, b in items:

        if  b ==  hashlib.md5(_email.encode('utf')).hexdigest():

            response = make_response()
            response.headers['NewSession'] = 'new'
            return LoginPassed(name)
        return LoginError()
```

I am using python 3x

If I can find the name of the cookie, how do I read its value to compare with something on my if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value = request.cookies.get('sessionid')
# The request.cookies.get(nome_do_cookie) returns the value of the cookie

    if  value ==  hashlib.md5(_email.encode('utf')).hexdigest():
        print(value)
        print(hashlib.md5(_email.encode('utf')).hexdigest())

        response = make_response()
        response.headers['NewSession'] = 'new'
        return LoginPassed(name)
    return LoginError()
```

The problem was that I did not notice I was doing the wrong checking.